# Request-URI Too Large при прокладывании маршрута

Tags: google-maps-api

народ подскажите 
хочу сделать карты экскурсий (порядка 13-17 вейпоинтов)
 вот код который выводит карту

```
  function chlist (exid){

     var start = "Россия, Москва, "+ exs[exid].start;
var end = "Россия, Москва, "+exs[exid].stop;
var waypts = [];
for (var i = 0; i < exs[exid].waypoints.length; i++) {
    waypts.push({
        location:"Россия, Москва, "+exs[exid].waypoints[i],
        stopover:true});

}

var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    waypoints: waypts,
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
};
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
   }

  });
```

};

если вейпоинтов мало то  все работает нормально но если их 12  и больше то выдается
Request-URI Too Large 
как такое  обойти ? у кого какие идеи?

Answer (score 1):

Каждую точку типа "Россия, Москва, ул. Такая-то, д.22" преобразовывать в координаты. Отправляется же GET запрос, а его длина ограничена ~2000 символов, включая адрес и разные дополнительные параметры. Но и тут тоже может не хватить. Тогда длинные пути разделять на несколько коротких.